# Cannot create Android Studio app with Seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android Studio running Java, anytime I run an app with a Seekbar, for example:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBar timesSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timesSeekBar);

        timesSeekBar.setMax(20);
        timesSeekBar.setProgress(10);

        timesSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Log.i("Info: ", Integer.toString(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following errors upon compilation:

```
2020-05-08 15:00:06.561 4501-4501/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.562 4501-4501/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-05-08 15:00:06.611 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/x86
2020-05-08 15:00:06.656 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.694 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:14)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.695 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:14)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.696 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
2020-05-08 15:00:06.697 4501-4501/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
2020-05-08 15:00:07.218 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-05-08 15:00:07.218 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-05-08 15:00:07.218 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-05-08 15:00:07.219 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2020-05-08 15:00:07.235 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa75850c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-05-08 15:00:07.295 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa75850c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa75831d0)
2020-05-08 15:00:07.309 4501-4532/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa75850c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa75831d0)
```

I have already deleted and reinstalled Android studio and have tried several different times to create said app, but I have gotten nowhere. Could I please get some help with this?

Comment: Can you share your view xml and `styles.xml`?